# MS Access - Create multiple reports based on 1 dropdown selection

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I have an Access DB that is used to track employee quality audits. A team completes the audits and would like to send a report each quarter to each of the employees with their findings. This could be 60+ reports each quarter. What I would like to create for them is a reporting tool that will allow them to select a Manager and click a button that will generate a report for each of the employees that report to that manager.

Is this possible to do without creating a report for each employee and calling each report based on the manager selected? Because of employee movement (terminations, transfers, promotions, etc.) I would like to see if a solution is possible dynamically but I am not sure how to accomplish it.

The table used for the report lists all of the audit details such as who the manager is. This may change during a quarter and be updated in the table so that audits follow the employee to their next manager; so the reports would need to be based on who the manager is as shown in the table.

I'm sorry if I left out any pertinent information; please let me know if you need any more information and Thank you in advance for any help you are willing to provide.

Comment: Either design one report object that outputs each employee record to look like individual report and apply filter of ManagerID to report or use VBA to open a filtered recordset, loop through recordset and open/close report applying filter of EmployeeID from recordset. The first option sounds simpler to me. Question is too broad.

Comment: Ideally, what I am looking for to do is have access generate multiple reports at one time based on the Manager name selected. So if a manager has 6 employees for example, when you select the managers name and click a button, a report for each employee will open/be created.

Comment: That's what I described in my comment.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I appreciate your help.